# TableView Row Selected Problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have tab based application with 2 tabs -> *Home* and *News*.

In my *News* tab I have a table with 2 rows, *General News*, *sports news*.

When I click *General News*, I want to show my RSS View. (With button to return to the News tab)

Please can someone tell me how to do this, I looked online and its very confusing.

Thanks a million.

Comment: im assuming i've to use indexPathForSelectedRow , check what one was clicked and load the view assigned to that  :(  < aaaawwwww im so annoyed with this

Comment: You've only seen the tip of the iceberg, bud :)  This is where the fun begins.  Sounds like you're on the right track though.  Remember, there a ton of tutorials around for this kinda stuff if you google it so don't pull all your hair out just yet.  Just a hint, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of the `uitableview` works good for pushing on new views too

Answer (score 0):

I created a controller and in the .m file I did the following

// Override to support row selection in the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"General News"])
    {

        Red *red = [[Red alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsView2" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:red animated:YES];
        [red release];

    }

else if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Traffic Reports"])
{
    Blue *blue = [[Blue alloc] initWithNibName:@"TrafficReports" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:blue animated:YES];
    [blue release];
}
else if ([[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Weather"])
{
    Blue *blue = [[Blue alloc] initWithNibName:@"WeatherView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:blue animated:YES];
    [blue release];
}
```

}

Comment: You've got exactly the right idea. One thing though- you don't need to call `deselectRowAtIndexPath` if you're pushing a new view controller onto the navigation controller.